# Dirac equation vs relativistic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics, computational-physics, dirac-equation

The [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure) can be derived by considering the relativistic Hamiltonian and also adding corrections for magnetic fields, etc.

For hydrogen these effects are small, which makes it easy to obtain an analytic solution using [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) (which involved writing the relativistic kinetic energy as a Taylor series in $v/c$ and only going out to the $v^4/c^4$ term). However, it is not *necessary* to do so as the complete Hamiltonian could also be solved numerically.

For inner orbitals of heavy elements the relativistic effect is large and is solved using the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation). Why can't the relativistic Hamiltonian be used instead (but solved numerically without perturbation theory) for these strongly relativistic systems?

Comment: How do you derive the fine structure constant?  Is there a formula?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke. It is not derived from first principles, it is measured in the lab. Measuring Planck's constant, the electron charge, etc is basically measuring how huge and massive humans are. Instead, alpha is inferred from a variety of effects that never touch the human scale, see https://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6385/191. The formula (i.e. what relates alpha to what dimensionless numbers you calculate in your instruments) varies depending on what is being measured.

Answer (score -1):

The Hamiltonian associated with the Dirac equation is not really the Hamiltonian for any physical system.  The reason is that the "relativistic Hamiltonian" you speak of assumes that there is a fixed, finite number of fermions—and this is never really true.  There is always the presence of the Dirac sea of negative-energy electrons (and muons, and quarks, etc.), filling up all of space around us.  You cannot describe the true Hamiltonian for this infinite number of fermions without using a field theory, which has a continuous number of degrees of freedom and which cannot be diagonalized exactly.  (Perturbation theory is required.)

For problems, like the hydrogen atom with an idealized (pointlike, infinitely massive) proton, that have just one electron, you can often finesse your way around these issues to a certain extent.  However, if you want to deal with a multi-electron atom, the field theory phenomena are avoidable.  With multiple electrons, you have to start accounting for exchange phenomena, in which the Fermi-Dirac statistics of the identical particles affect the structure of the wave function.  In a two-electron atom, like neutral helium, you can envision that the electrons are constantly scattering off each other, and the scattering process includes both direct and exchange scattering (in which the electrons switch places).  However, when you start to include relativistic corrections, you also have to account for exchange scattering off the negative-energy electrons filling the Dirac sea.  There is thus no way to get an exact picture of the theory without using a Hamiltonian that includes the full infinite number of particles—meaning that you have to use a field theory.

Comment: So there are three approaches?
1. Change the Hamiltonian and solve the Schrodinger equation.
2. Solve the Dirac equation instead.
3. Full-on quantum field theory.

So is 1 the least accurate, 2 more accurate, and 3 the most accurate?